# Was Captain Ginyu in his original body at the start of the Freeza Saga?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

Is the purple body with horns that we see his, or did he steal it prior to the Freeza saga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

From [dragonball.wikia.com](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Ginyu):

> Like the other members of the Ginyu Force, Ginyu's special powers originated during his childhood. When Ginyu first learned of his Body Change ability, he swapped bodies with the richest kid in his class, which made him popular with girls but also stupid, and he soon realized that men should compete in terms of strength rather than money. Only a few people have seen Ginyu's true form, and Salza is among them